# Trying to redirect a link doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect this link. When users go here:

```
campnubar.org/50/booklet
```

I want to redirect them to the below link

```
http://campnubar.org/MyNubar/booklet.php
```

I tried:

```
redirect 301 50/booklet 

http://campnubar.org/MyNubar/booklet.php
```

How can I make it work properly?

Comment: You're putting that in a htaccess file, right? Not just on the page as HTML?

Comment: What programming language are you using to redirect?

Comment: Yes I'm using an htcaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Redirect /50/booklet http://campnubar.org/MyNubar/booklet.php
```